# Magento: overriding AccountController interferes with register

Tags: php, magento

I needed to change the editPostAction so I created my own AccountController and copied the editPostAction. But suddenly the customer registration no longer works, I get a lot of errors that certain address fields cannot be empty (despite having been filled out). My config.xml looks like this:

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <customer>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <my_ext before="Mage_Customer_AccountController">My_Ext</my_ext >
                    <!--my_ext before="Mage_Customer_AddressController">My_Ext</my_ext -->
                </modules>
            </args>
        </customer>
    </routers>
</frontend>
```

And the AccountController looks like this:

```
require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers','Mage_Customer').DS."AccountController.php";
class My_Ext_AccountController extends Mage_Customer_AccountController{

    public function editPostAction(){
        //..copied code from Mage_Customer_AccountController 
    }
}
```

If I remove the part from my config.xml, the customer registration works again. I don't see why this is happening, did anyone ever encounter this problem? editPostAction shouldn't even interfere with customer registration, right? And since I didn't use an other of the AccountController methods, I don't understand this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me before, it's getting embarassing. The problem was, that another existing extension (not written by me, so there's my excuse) was already overriding the AccountController. Their extension modified the register process and my config.xml undid their changes. So what I did was this:

```
<?php
require_once "Otherextension/CustomerRegistration/controllers/AccountController.php";
class My_Ext_AccountController extends Otherextension_CustomerRegistration_AccountController{
    public function editPostAction(){
        //... 
    }
}
```

so instead of extending the Mage AccountController I used the Otherextension AccountController which, in turn, extends the Mage AccountController.

Maybe this helps someone else.